# CakePHP - Validation rule 'last' not working

Tags: validation, cakephp

I have two custom validation rules (I have tested they work correctly):

```
class PasswordResetKey extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(

        'timestamp' => array(
            'rule' => '_notExpired',
            'message' => 'Your password reset link has expired. Please request another one.',
            'last' => true
        ),

        'key' => array(
            'rule' => '_validFormat',
            'message' => 'You do not appear to have used a valid password reset link. Please request another one.'
        )

    );
```

But no matter what I do, the errors returned are always:

```
Array
(
    [key] => You do not appear to have used a valid password reset link. Please request another one.
    [timestamp] => Your password reset link has expired. Please request another one.
)
```

Even when I check that the timestamp rule fails, it still goes on and checks the other rule for 'key' as well. I only want the timestamp error if it is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

last is for multi rules per field. due to the fact that you only have one rule per field its always last and thus pointless.

Comment: Ah, right.  OK so is there any way to do this other than in the controller checking which errors were returned and only using the one I want?

Answer (score 0):

My intuition says `_notExpired` should not fire if the reset link is wrong. I would have that rule raise a flag only if the link is correct but expired.